# What’s a simple workflow for bulk deleting emails from Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Now that [Mailstrom](https://mailstrom.co/) is no longer free, I am looking for a way to move or delete email messages within Gmail in bulk.

I don't want to set up a filter which will affect new messages, just move and delete existing messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the advanced search page to search for existing messages. In other words you can create an ad hoc filter.

Once you have identified all the messages that meet your criteria, you can then select them. It doesn't matter if the number of messages returned is a handful or thousands all can be selected at the same time. Once you have selected them, they can be labeled, relabeled, archived, or even deleted.

Comment: This allows me to add a new label but not remove the inbox label if I want to move rather than delete.

Comment: The archive button/command removes the inbox label.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to delete/archive/mark as read a whole bunch of emails at once?

First, decide which emails you want selected and type in a search within your email. That could be all the emails in your inbox (label:inbox, social, promotion etc.,). It could be emails from a certain person (from:xxxx@gmail.com). It could be between certain dates, all sent mail, all social email, you decide (check here for info on how to make advanced searches).

Once you’ve made that search in Gmail, go ahead and click the check box in the top left and select All. You’ll see a link pop up just below the button that looks something like this:

Go ahead and click the “select all conversations that match this search” link and take the action you wish to take. Easy as that!

Comment: I don't think this link exists anymore in Gmail.